# how can pass this regular expression in C# ?about"[]" mean

Tags: regular-language

I have the following regular expression:

```
^[A-Z&&[^EIOSTUYZ]][X|0-9&&[^4-6]][A-F[NWX]].?.?$
```

I don't how can pass this regular expression. I trid AW0AW,AXFX,3D0E, but all can't pass it.

Comment: `1` Where is that regex taken from? `2` Why do you need to find a string that matches it? `3` What are you actually trying to do? `4` Is this related to programming?

Comment: i need take some java source tern to C#. i only have source but no file.so, i only can try to how word can pass this regular in C#.